# Does this implementation of the "Context Pattern" look ok?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have multiple processing units that might exist in an array, each with their own parameters. I would like to communicate the parameters of each processing unit using the *context pattern* after it was suggested as a [solution to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398852/is-there-a-recommended-design-pattern-for-communicating-parameters-with-a-proces). However, I am unable to find simple C++ examples of the pattern online. I have made a simplified implementation below for your inspection. The code works and compiles just fine, but **am I implementing the pattern correctly?** Any and all suggestions for style improvements would be most welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <map>

class cParamsContext
{      
     typedef std::map<std::string, float> myMap_t; //Make the return type of getter less wordy
     myMap_t paramMap;

public:              
    cParamsContext()
    {
        paramMap["a0"] = 1.f;
        paramMap["a1"] = 2.f;
    }

    myMap_t const& getMap() const {return paramMap;} //Return read-only alias   
};

class cProcessUnit
{
    float parameter;
    int id;

public:
    cProcessUnit(cParamsContext &contextObj, int id_) : parameter (0.f), id(id_)
    {
        std::stringstream idStream;
        idStream << id;

        std::string key = std::string( "a" + idStream.str() );

        if(contextObj.getMap().find( key ) != contextObj.getMap().end())        
            parameter = contextObj.getMap().find( key )->second; // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402354/using-overloaded-operator-via-an-accessor-function#10402452                 
    }

    float getParam() {return parameter;}
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cParamsContext contextObj;


    for (int nn=0; nn<3; nn++)
    {
        cProcessUnit temp(contextObj, nn);
        std::cout << "Processing unit "  << nn << " param = " << temp.getParam() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, can you suggest how I could make the parameters within each class update themselves should the parameter map change?

The output looks like this incase you were interested  . . . .

```
Processing unit 0 param = 1
Processing unit 1 param = 2
Processing unit 2 param = 0
```

Comment: This should go on Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like a valid implementation.  Does it pass your tests?  I'm not experienced using a context pattern in this particular way, but it does look fine to me.

As for updating values, I'm currently doing something very similar in a project I've been assigned and I'm using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  The `cParamsContext` would be the *observable* in this case.  I'm using a [signal/slot / event/delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359928/) implementation of the observer pattern.  So far, it has worked wonders for my task.

Comment: Excellent idea with setting `cParamsContext` observable. +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it will work ok, but here are a few suggestions:

1. consider using a hash map/table which will be more performant. Boost hast one that you can look at. The std::map is fine performance wise, but depending on the data-set, a hash table could be more performant.
2. consider templatizing the values, or at least allow for different types by creating a map for each type and corresponding getters/setters. As it is now, the parameters being used can only be float, but what if a different parameter is needed in the future?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but please elaborate (1) What is wrong with std::map and (2) what values am I templatizing and what benefits would this afford me? PLease be explicit.