# Using overloaded operator[] via an accessor function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, accessor

I have an accessor function that returns a const reference to a type (std::map) ... ...

```
myMap_t const& getMap() const {return paramMap;}
```

The type has an overloaded `[]` operator. What is the syntax to then use the `[]` operator directly from the getter function in a way like the following, but that actually works.

```
parameter = contextObj.getMap()[key];
```

Error message is:

```
context.cpp:35: error: passing   
  'const std::map<
     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
     float, 
     std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
     std::allocator<std::pair<
       const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
       float> > >'
as 'this' argument of 
  '_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&)  
with 
  _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
  _Tp = float, 
  _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  td::allocator<char> > >, 
  _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<
    const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
    float> >]' 
discards qualifiers
```

Comment: Does it work if you surround the call in parentheses? `(contextObj.getMap())[key]`

Comment: `parameter = contextObj.getMap()([key]);` gives context.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token

Comment: Other part. The `. and []` share the same precedence.

Comment: Is `myMap_t::operator[]` labled as `const`?  If not, you can't use it on a `myMap_t const&`

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` only works on non-`const` objects.

Comment: And the reason it is not const is because it actually inserts an element if one does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `operator[]` in a map is a mutating operation, and you cannot call it on a const reference to a map. The reason that it is mutating is that it must return a reference to a value, and for that, if the key was not already present in the container, it will insert a new default constructed value addressed by that key and return the reference to it.

If you have a const reference, and you want to determine whether an element is present (or access it), you must use `std::map<>::find` that will return an iterator. If the element is not present the value of the iterator would be `m.end()`

Comment: So how do I get the value from the iterator? `if(contextObj.getMap().find( key ) != contextObj.getMap().end())        
            parameter = contextObj.getMap().find( key );`

Comment: Got it `parameter = contextObj.getMap().find( key )->second`

Comment: @learnvst: To be honest, I would change the interface. Rather than granting access to the map and letting users search in it, I would provide accessors to the data elements directly: `T getParam( std::string key, T const & default ) { auto it = paramMap.find(key); if ( it == paramMap.end() ) return default; else return it->second; }` or something similar... The use of a map (or any other container) should be an implementation detail, and users don't need to hold the burden of searching it.

Answer (score 3):

You return the `std::map` by const reference, but `std::map::operator[]` is not a const function, because sometimes it needs to alter the map.
To solve this, you should do one of the following:
(A) Use `.find` instead of `[]`

```
auto iter = contextObj.getMap().find( key );
if (iter != contextObj.getMap().end())
    param = iter->second;
```

(B) Return the map as non const (not recommended)
(C) Make a wrapper class (not worth it most of the time)

Comment: To be clear, the choices A, B, C, are alternatives. You may solve your problem with any one of those strategies, you don't need all of them.

Comment: How do I get the value from the iterator?

Comment: Got it `parameter = contextObj.getMap().find( key )->second`

Answer (score 1):

You return a `const myMap_t&` from your method `getMap()`. From your error message `myMap_t` is a typedef for a `std::map`. Ther `operator[]` of `std::map` needs a modifiable object (can't be called on const), since it can insert items into the map (if no item with the specified key exists, it will insert one into the map and return a reference to that one).
To solve that problem you have two options:

- Use `contextObj.getMap().find(key)` instead of `contextObj.getMap()[key]` to get an iterator to the element (or to `map.end()` if it doesn't exist)
- return `myMap_t&` (without const) to get a modifiable object on which `operator[]` can be called

Comment: How do I get the value from the iterator?

Comment: Got it `parameter = contextObj.getMap().find( key )->second`

Answer (score 1):

```
context.cpp:35: error: passing   
  'const std::map<
     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
     float, 
     std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
     std::allocator<std::pair<
       const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
       float> > >'
as 'this' argument of 
  '_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&)  
with 
  _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
  _Tp = float, 
  _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  td::allocator<char> > >, 
  _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<
    const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
    float> >' 
discards qualifiers
```

`std::basic_string` is the template used to implement `std::string`, and indeed `std::string` is simply the instantiation based on `char`. So substitute that in first:

```
context.cpp:35: error: passing   
  'const std::map<
     std::string, 
     float, 
     std::less<std::string>, 
     std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, float> >
  >'
as 'this' argument of 
  '_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&)  
with 
  _Key = std::string,
  _Tp = float, 
  _Compare = std::less<std::string>, 
  _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string> >' 
discards qualifiers
```

We don't really care about the `_Compare` (comparison function) and `_Alloc` (allocator) arguments for our map, since we're just using the defaults; so let's ignore those, and let's also substitute the `_Key` and `_Tp` values into the template description:

```
context.cpp:35: error: passing   
  'const std::map<std::string, float>'
as 'this' argument of 
  'float& std::map<std::string, float>::operator[](const std::string&)  
discards qualifiers
```

There we go, much simpler. We're using the `operator[]` of our `std::map<std::string, float>`, and we're trying to use it on a `const std::map<std::string, float>` (i.e., that's what we're using as the `this` argument for the call). This "discards qualifiers", specifically, the `const` qualifier.

The compiler is telling you that the `operator[]` of the map does not promise to keep the map `const`, i.e. it is allowed to change the map. And that is a compiler error, because the code is written with the built-in assertion that the map won't change.

Why would the map change? Well, look at the documentation:

> If x matches the key of an element in the container, the function returns a reference to its mapped value.
>
> If x does not match the key of any element in the container, the function *inserts a new element with that key* and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the map size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).

(Emphasis mine).

Inserting an element is certainly a modification.

Why does it do this? Well, [we already have a question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639544/why-does-stdmap-operator-create-an-object-if-the-key-doesnt-exist).